# cannot authenticate the tumblr

Tags: android, authentication, authorization, tumblr

I used the code, which is mentioned in the link https://github.com/FredrikL/android-ttTumblr. When i use this code, i cannot authenticate the username and password. can any one help me plz.. The following code is i m using for authenticate the tumblr

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                "http://www.tumblr.com/api/authenticate");

        try {
            System.out.println("user name : "+Username);
            System.out.println("password : "+Password);
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", Username));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", Password));

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            System.out.println("response value : "+ response.toString());
            System.out.println("response entity : "+response.getStatusLine().toString());
            System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
            if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
                return false;
            }
            // Save our list of available blogs.
            SharedPreferences blogs = this.context.getSharedPreferences(BLOGS_PREFS,
                    0);
            Log.d("ttT", "attempting blog list extraction");
            saveBlogList(response, blogs);
            return true;

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "client proto exception", e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "io exception", e);
        }
        return false;
```

in this i m getting "response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() value is 404". plz anyone help me to authenticate it.

Comment: the page doesn't exist. hence the 404

Answer (score 0):

http://www.tumblr.com/api/authenticate does not exist.  Therefore you get an HTTP404.

See this

http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2

Comment: i followed above link and tried to post the text but i cant post it. i got the access token and secret value and got the authentication success message. i user the following code:

Comment: HttpPost hpost = new HttpPost("http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/" + blogname.getText().toString() + ".tumblr.com/post");
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type", "text"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("title", title));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("body", body));
try 
{
hpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
}
catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) 
{
debug += e.toString();
}

Comment: consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
consumer.setTokenWithSecret(token, secret);
try 
{
consumer.sign(hpost);
}
catch (OAuthMessageSignerException e) 
{
debug += e.toString();
}
catch (OAuthExpectationFailedException e) 
{
debug += e.toString();
}
catch (OAuthCommunicationException e) 
{
debug += e.toString();
}

Comment: DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse resp = null;
try 
{
resp = client.execute(hpost);
}
catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
{
debug += e.toString();
}
catch (IOException e) 
{
debug += e.toString();
}
String result = null;
try {
result = EntityUtils.toString(resp.getEntity());
} catch (ParseException e) 
{
debug += e.toString();
} catch (IOException e) 
{
debug += e.toString();
}

Comment: the  result value for above code is : {"meta":{"status":401,"msg":"Not Authorized"},"response":[]} is i missed anything? plz help me..

Comment: this is impossible to read in comments.  Please start a new question - but 401 "not authorized" looks pretty clear to me